# Specific floating elements

Tags: css, css-float

I have standrat floating grid, somethig like:

```
ul li{
   width:300px;
   float:left;
}
```

I need to 4th element go under 3thd one. Like on the picture.

thanks for your advise!

[image]

Comment: This will depend heavily on the markup you use. Please post your code (enough to reproduce the issue).

Comment: columns are ul list
<ul><li> Column1</li><li>Column2</li><li> Column3</li><li>Column4</li><li>Column5</li></ul>
So number 4 need to go under 3. Like on the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a duct tape solution but could it be fixed by putting Column 3 & 4 in the same container?

eg:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      (Column 1)
  </li>
  <li>
      (Column 2)
  </li>
  <li>
      <div style="float:left;">
          (Column 3), (Column 4)
      </div>
  </li>
  <li>
      (Column 5)
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: a list genarated dinamicly by php. it possible to do that manipulation by javascript,after dom loaded

Answer (score 0):

So here is one solution depended on ForeverStuck idea. 
Little jQuery:

```
//Select element3 and 4 wrap them as li
$('ul > li:nth-child(3), ul > li:nth-child(4)').wrapAll( "<li />");
//Then unwrap inside li elements, so 3 and 4 become 3 element
$('.homepage .box-category > li > li > a').unwrap();
```